# how does xmpp make a real time connection

Tags: websocket, xmpp, real-time

time connections topic and i heard about xmpp and i have a questiosn about this protocol

[https://medium.com/@thinkwik/web-sockets-vs-xmpp-which-is-better-for-chat-application-113e3520b327#:~:text=XMPP%20protocol%20supports%20the%20transmission,applications%20include%20Gtalk%20and%20Whatsapp](https://medium.com/@thinkwik/web-sockets-vs-xmpp-which-is-better-for-chat-application-113e3520b327#:%7E:text=XMPP%20protocol%20supports%20the%20transmission,applications%20include%20Gtalk%20and%20Whatsapp).

i read this link about xmpp. and i couldn't understand this part

XMPP protocol supports the transmission of current information such as data. **As a messaging protocol, it can only be applied effectively by moving through an appropriate transport binding such as TCP/IP, HTTP, or WebSocket**

and i read somewhere that it can run on websocket. what does that mean ? can explain a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 7395](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7395) specifies how XMPP can run over top of WebSockets.  From a high level, each XMPP stanza goes in exactly one WebSocket message.